# Tempus Dominus minDate counld not parse

Tags: momentjs, tempus-dominus-datetimepicker

First time using `Tempus Dominus Datetimepicker` for `Bootstrap 4`.

In my code I have:

```
var dateFormat = 'DD-MM-YYYY';
var CurrDate   = '27-06-2018';
var MinDate    = '27-06-1918';
var MaxDate    = '27-06-2018';
```

I then convert the dates to `moment` objects:

```
dateMin = moment(CurrDate, dateFormat);
dateMin = moment(MinDate, dateFormat);
dateMax = moment(MaxDate, dateFormat);
```

I can see the `moment` objects in `console.log()`, dates are correct.

```
Moment {_isAMomentObject: true, _i: "27-06-2018", _f: "DD-MM-YYYY", _isUTC: false, _pf: {…}, …}
Moment {_isAMomentObject: true, _i: "27-06-1918", _f: "DD-MM-YYYY", _isUTC: false, _pf: {…}, …}
Moment {_isAMomentObject: true, _i: "27-06-2018", _f: "DD-MM-YYYY", _isUTC: false, _pf: {…}, …}
```

I then initialise the `datetimepicker` like this:

```
// Initialize Stand Alone datetimepicker
$('#myDiv').datetimepicker({
    format: dateFormat,
    date: dateCurr,
    minDate: dateMin,
    maxDate: dateMax,
});
```

But it fails with:

```
minDate() Could not parse date parameter: NaN
```

Why is the `datepicker` not happy with a `moment`? The [instructions here](https://tempusdominus.github.io/bootstrap-4/Options/#minmaxdate) say it should work. Have I missed / messed up something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code seems to be working fine:

```js
$(function() {
  var dateFormat = "DD-MM-YYYY";
  var CurrDate = "27-06-2018";
  var MinDate = "01-06-2018";
  var MaxDate = "27-06-2018";
  
  dateCurr = moment(CurrDate, dateFormat);
  dateMin = moment(MinDate, dateFormat);
  dateMax = moment(MaxDate, dateFormat);
  
  $("#datetimepicker1").datetimepicker({
    format: dateFormat,
    date: dateCurr,
    minDate: dateMin,
    maxDate: dateMax,
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.1.0/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tempusdominus-bootstrap-4/5.0.0-alpha14/css/tempusdominus-bootstrap-4.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container mt-3">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="input-group date" id="datetimepicker1" data-target-input="nearest">
          <input type="text" class="form-control datetimepicker-input" data-target="#datetimepicker1" />
          <div class="input-group-append" data-target="#datetimepicker1" data-toggle="datetimepicker">
            <div class="input-group-text"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tempusdominus-bootstrap-4/5.0.0-alpha14/js/tempusdominus-bootstrap-4.min.js"></script>
```

Check that you included:

- jQuery
- moment.js
- tempusdominus-bootstrap-4.js